# Why does || operator work in my situation

Tags: c++

Why is this an infinite loop using || logical operator

```
char c;
std::cin >> c;
while( c != 'y' || c != 'Y' || c != 'N' || c != 'n')
```

but this is not

```
while( c != 'y' && c != 'Y' && c != 'N' && c != 'n')
```

I don't understand why && operator work here because logically thinking  || operator is better fit.

Comment: Think about when `c != 'y' || c != 'Y'` would ever become `false`. Hint: Use de Morgans law to invert the condtion.

Comment: Can you give an example character that should cause that condition to ever be false?

Comment: first thing is "c is one of 'y', 'Y', 'N', 'n'". Second is "c is at the same time 'y', 'Y', 'N', 'n'", that ofc cannot happen. Still the while is misplaced. you probably want do { cin ... } while (c != .. && c != ...);

Comment: @Exceptyon   The first thing is actually `c` is NOT 'y' or NOT 'Y' or NOT 'N'` or NOT 'n'.    What you say would be true if the comparisons used `==` but they are using `!=`.

Answer (score 2):

Lets just look at the very smallest part:

```
c != 'Y' || c != 'N'
```

If c is 'Y' then it is not 'N', if it is 'N' then it is not 'Y'. Aka:

```
c  |  c != 'Y' || c != 'N'
Y  |     1     ||   0      =  1
N  |     0     ||   1      =  1
?  |     1     ||   1      =  1
```

If your logic always returns 1 no matter what, the loop will run forever. I assume you are looking to wait until you get `c` as one of these values, so write it logically.

> I want to wait until c is one of ['y', 'Y', ...]

And you might be able to write some nicer code:

```
std::array<char> options = {{'y', 'Y', 'n', 'N'}};

while (std::none_of(std::begin(options), std::end(options), 
         [&c](char check) { return check == c; };)) {
    std::cout << "Hey write the correct character!\n";
}
```

*Untested!*

Answer (score -1):

You are checking the condition which is always true by using `||` operator,
`( c != 'y' || c != 'Y' || c != 'N' || c != 'n')`

This is always true ,because it would always satisfy at-least 3 conditions in your conditional statement .

if your char is `n` then it would satisfy remaining conditions
`c!='y'` , `c!='Y'` , `c!='N'` and similarly for any other character